# Configuring proxy Squid under Strongswan private network

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy, squid, strongswan

I cannot connect to Proxy Server (*Squid*) from my computer (*Windows 10*) via VPN (*StrongSwan, IKev2*) on my VPS (*CentOS 8*)

I have no idea what I'm doing, so please bare with me!

1. Port in firewall-cmd is opened, firewall restarted
2. My computer is connected to VPN and has 10.20.30.1 Virtual IP: [strongswan statusall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWUF1.png)
3. I have this route created: [ip route 220](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZ1Ws.png)

If I try to connect like this it fails:
[curl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmPuV.png)

If I try to connect with public IP it works (It won't let me because of squid rules ofc)

Please, give me ideas on how it can be done with private IP?
What am I missing? (apart from clear understanding of how it all works)

/etc/squid/squid.conf:

```
# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt to list your (internal) IP networks from where browsing
# should be allowed

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210         # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280         # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488         # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591         # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777         # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

#
# Recommended minimum Access Permission configuration:
#
# Deny requests to certain unsafe ports
http_access deny !Safe_ports

# Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

# Only allow cachemgr access from localhost
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager

# We strongly recommend the following be uncommented to protect innocent
# web applications running on the proxy server who think the only
# one who can access services on "localhost" is a local user
#http_access deny to_localhost

#
# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
#

acl mynet src 10.20.30.0/32
acl mynet src 192.168.0.0/16

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt localnet in the ACL section to list your (internal) IP networks
# from where browsing should be allowed
http_access allow mynet

# And finally deny all other access to this proxy
http_access deny all

# Squid normally listens to port 3128
http_port 13333

# Uncomment and adjust the following to add a disk cache directory.
#cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 100 16 256

# Leave coredumps in the first cache dir
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid

#
# Add any of your own refresh_pattern entries above these.
#
refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:        1440    0%      1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0     0%      0
refresh_pattern .               0       20%     4320
```

If you're interested of what I'm trying to do:
Tunneling Internet traffic from my browser through VPN, while keeping rest of it in the clear.
I will have to figure out routing of DNS calls later.